# UITableView - return custom instance of cell from cellForRowAt

Tags: swift, uitableview

I have this method inside `UITableViewController` that is part of navigation:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    return sections[indexPath.section]
}
```

sections is an array of:

```
var sections: [DetailCell] = []
```

where `DetailCell` is my custom cell inherited from `UITableViewCell`. I fill this array from outside of `UITableViewController`.

When I show the table for the first time, cell is visible. When I go back and forth in navigation controller, cell is no longer visible (and `cellForRowAt` is called, returning the same instance).
When I create new instance of `DetailCell` inside `cellForRowAt`, it works correctly.

What is wrong?

Comment: Why are you trying to create and maintain an array of cells, instead of using `.dequeueReusableCell(...)` ?